# Why is my workflow status column intermittently blank

Tags: workflow, status

So this is weird, I've done a lot of searching but could not find any answers out there.

Occasionally the 'Workflow Status' column is blank, even though a workflow is "In Progress". Today, one of my users added 4 items, all four workflows started but one of them does not have anything in the status column. This is happening to multiple sites under the same site collection.

SharePoint 2010, there is only one workflow on the library, let me know if more detail is needed.

Comment: Check the workflow timer job. Try to run it. Also check log files for more information.

Answer (score 3):

How many lookup columns do you have on the list view, there cannot be more than 8 on a view by default, unless you have changed this in the central admin. 
Remember that the people columns like 'created by' 'modified by' also count as lookups.

The workflow status column is a lookup that links to the Workflow history list. 
If you have more than 8 lookups in the view, this seems to affect this column and it keeps dropping.

Another thing to look out for is the "Workflow Auto Clean up' timer job, which deletes this column after 60 days after the workflow status change to Completed. Although I believe that this is not the case in your issue.

Comment: The only lookups are the default ones you mentioned, but that's helpful to know.